# Extract keys words from pandas dataframe column, but not nested keywords

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Pandas DataFrame` that contains two  free-form text columns where people describe the model or trim level of their vehicle (e.g.: LE, 1LT, RS, SS, etc.).  In these columns, some people will have just the model (e.g.: LE), other people will add additional text (e.g.: 2dr Convertible SS w/2SS).  In addition, the model levels have a certain hierarchy, in that SS < 1SS < 2SS.

I want to extract the these models or trim levels and create a new column in my dataframe (e.g.: 1ls = 1LS, ZL-1 = ZL1, etc.)

```
# the model can be stored in either 'submodel' or 'trim'
data = [{'SubModel': 'SS-EDITION', 'Trim': 'SS-EDITION(MANUAL 6 SPEED)  Coupe 2-Door'},
        {'SubModel': 'ZL1', 'Trim': 'ZL1 Coupe 2-Door'},
        {'SubModel': 'N/A', 'Trim': 'SS TRANSFORMER'},
        {'SubModel': '1LT RS AUTO BLUETOOTH REAR CAM', 'Trim': 'N/A'},
        {'SubModel': 'N/A', 'Trim': 'LS'},
        {'SubModel': 'Camaro SS', 'Trim': 'Camaro SS'},
        {'SubModel': 'Dusk Edition', 'Trim': 'N/A'},
        {'SubModel': 'Camaro SS W/ RS Pkg', 'Trim': 'Camaro SS W/ RS Pkg'},
        {'SubModel': '2dr Coupe SS w/2SS', 'Trim': '2dr Coupe SS w/2SS'},
        {'SubModel': '2dr Convertible LT w/1LT', 'Trim': '2dr Convertible LT w/1LT'},
        {'SubModel': 'N/A', 'Trim': '2LT'},
        {'SubModel': "LT RS 6-SPD SUNROOF REAR CAM 20'S", 'Trim': '1LT Coupe 2-Door'},
        {'SubModel': '2dr Convertible SS w/2SS', 'Trim': '2dr Convertible SS w/2SS'},
        {'SubModel': '2dr Convertible LT w/2LT', 'Trim': '2dr Convertible LT w/2LT'},
        {'SubModel': 'N/A', 'Trim': '2LT'},
        {'SubModel': 'N/A', 'Trim': 'RARE ZL1 - LOW MILES'},
        {'SubModel': "2SS AUTO LEATHER NAV HUD 20'S", 'Trim': 'SS Coupe 2-Door'},
        {'SubModel': 'SS', 'Trim': 'SS Coupe 2-Door'},
        {'SubModel': 'N/A', 'Trim': 'Car'},
        {'SubModel': 'N/A', 'Trim': '2LT'}]

# load data into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create a dict of all models, including alternative spellings
models = {'LE' : 'LE',
          '1LE' : '1LE',
          '2LE' : '2LE',
          'LT' : 'LT',
          '1LT' : '1LT',
          '2LT' : '2LT',
          'LS' : 'LS',
          '1LS' : '1LS',
          '2LS' : '2LS',
          'SS' : 'SS',
          '1SS' : '1SS',
          '2SS' : '2SS',
          'ZL1' : 'ZL1',
          'ZL/1' : 'ZL1',
          'ZL-1' : 'ZL1',
          'COPO' : 'COPO',
          'copo' : 'copo'}

# look for each key in the models dict, and if found, return the value for that key for the column 'TRIM'
def trim_level(row):

    for key in models.keys():
        if key in (row['Trim'] or row['SubModel']):
            return models[key]


df['TRIM'] = df.apply(lambda row: trim_level(row), axis=1)
```

As seen below, my existing solution has a problem in that a 2SS is classified as a SS, or a 2LT is classified as an LT.  I also don't know what to do with people that include 2 different models in their description, such as SS w/2SS.

```
    +-----+-------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|     | TRIM  |             SubModel               |                  Trim                   |
+-----+-------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|  0  | SS    | SS-EDITION                         | SS-EDITION(MANUAL 6 SPEED) Coupe 2-Door |
|  1  | ZL1   | ZL1                                | ZL1 Coupe 2-Door                        |
|  2  | SS    | N/A                                | SS TRANSFORMER                          |
|  3  | None  | 1LT RS AUTO BLUETOOTH REAR CAM     | N/A                                     |
|  4  | LS    | N/A                                | LS                                      |
|  5  | SS    | Camaro SS                          | Camaro SS                               |
|  6  | None  | Dusk Edition                       | N/A                                     |
|  7  | SS    | Camaro SS W/ RS Pkg                | Camaro SS W/ RS Pkg                     |
|  8  | SS    | 2dr Coupe SS w/2SS                 | 2dr Coupe SS w/2SS                      |
|  9  | 1LT   | 2dr Convertible LT w/1LT           | 2dr Convertible LT w/1LT                |
| 10  | LT    | N/A                                | 2LT                                     |
| 11  | 1LT   | LT RS 6-SPD SUNROOF REAR CAM 20'S  | 1LT Coupe 2-Door                        |
| 12  | SS    | 2dr Convertible SS w/2SS           | 2dr Convertible SS w/2SS                |
| 13  | LT    | 2dr Convertible LT w/2LT           | 2dr Convertible LT w/2LT                |
| 14  | LT    | N/A                                | 2LT                                     |
| 15  | LE    | N/A                                | RARE ZL1 - LOW MILES                    |
| 16  | SS    | 2SS AUTO LEATHER NAV HUD 20'S      | SS Coupe 2-Door                         |
| 17  | SS    | SS                                 | SS Coupe 2-Door                         |
| 18  | None  | N/A                                | Car                                     |
| 19  | LT    | N/A                                | 2LT                                     |
+-----+-------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The 2SS is classified as SS because in your `trim_level()` function, you put `if key in (row['Trim'] or row['SubModel']):` meaning "if this key (SS) is in either of these cells, then put this key (SS) in the Trim column" - and that's exactly what's happening. The SS key is clearly in the string, which satisfies the if condition. Change your if statement to consider multiple keys being in the same string. In your particular case sounds like you want 2SS to win out if both SS and 2SS are found. No quick fix here IMO. You should go back and rethink the design of this.

Comment: @ralston Your interpretation of `if key in (row['Trim'] or row['SubModel'])` is incorrect, and this is exactly the OP's problem. The statement shall look like `if key in row['Trim'] or key in row['SubModel']`.